# Google Calendar API returning duplicate items in response

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-calendar-api

Making API call from serverless function. Locally the call returns correct, in production I'm getting duplicate results. Notice the ID on the items array for the first and last item.

```
{kind: "calendar#events", etag: ""p33gan841gmfv00g"", summary: "DFW Nets",…}
    accessRole: "owner"
    defaultReminders: []
    etag: "\"p33gan841gmfv00g\""
    items: [,…]
    0: {kind: "calendar#event", etag: ""3238943100952000"", id: "7e5jjq2eos56vn0dsrcr3bgbod_20210428T233000Z",…}
    1: {kind: "calendar#event", etag: ""3238991623418000"", id: "0b02a4ik62avudben41ec3bmfs_20210429T033000Z",…}
    2: {kind: "calendar#event", etag: ""3238946501106000"", id: "7p37af8hkuli5htepdmu5t6qf4_20210429T170000Z",…}
    3: {kind: "calendar#event", etag: ""3238943100952000"", id: "7e5jjq2eos56vn0dsrcr3bgbod_20210429T233000Z",…}
    kind: "calendar#events"
    summary: "DFW Nets"
    timeZone: "America/Chicago"
    updated: "2021-04-27T18:20:12.780Z"
code in the serverless function

    calendar.events.list({
      auth: oAuth2Client,
      calendarId: "8pv1frn7h2ml914el8cu7gb9a0@group.calendar.google.com",
      singleEvents: true,
      showDeleted: false,
      timeMin: today.toISOString(),
      maxResults: 10,
      timeMax: tomorrow.toISOString(),
      orderBy: "startTime"
    },
    (error, response) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return;
      }
      callback(null, {
        headers: {
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        },
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(response.data)
      });
    }
  );
};
```

To add to this, there are actually missing results as well in this production environment. API explorer is also returning correct results same as development. The issue is just in the bundled code hosted at netlify.

Note: the `timeMin` and `timeMax` are both in the correct format.
if I don't include `timeMax` - the results seem to display correctly?

Answer (score 1):

These are the recurring events - try setting the `singleEvents` property when you call `list`